# Why is the $RANDOM max 32767 and not 65535?

Tags: bash

The documentation for $RANDOM states:

> `$RANDOM` is an internal Bash function (not a constant) that returns a pseudorandom integer in the range 0 - 32767

If the random value is unsigned why does it only use a value up to 2^15 - 1 and not 2^16 - 1? Is there any significance to this?

Comment: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c#n1331

Comment: And [this thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2019-01/msg00137.html) seems relevant.

Comment: @choroba Notice that right before that function, `BASH_RAND_MAX` is set and even has a 32 bit option, but `BASH_RANDOM_16` is set to `1` right before that.

Comment: The only reference that I can find that somewhat may justify that value comes from the paper mentioned in the implementation where it is stated the following: "Turbo Pascal provides its own random number generator, which is not very good and maxint on this system is only 2^15 - 1, thereby eliminating the possibility of an efficient integer implementation."

Comment: @choroba Thanks for pointing me to the code. I see that `BASH_RAND_MAX` is 0x7fff for the 16 bit option. I'm trying to find out why it's not 0xffff i.e. why does it not use the most significant bit?

Comment: @CRM that seems to make sense to me. Thanks for finding this!